# Strange SSRS 2008 issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a strange issue with SSRS 2008 and I wonder if someone can shed any light. I have added the company domain users to the "Home" folder and set them to be "Browser", however normal users (i.e. those without admin rights) can access all the things that admins can access, i.e. Site Settings, security, etc. Which obviously we definitely dont want happening. Any ideas, is there some configuration I am missing or something?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Task ticked under the Browser Role and see if you have ticked rights not applicable to the role.

Security > Roles > Browser .. Properties.

should only be  (ticked)
view reports , view resources, view folders, manage individual subscriptions, view models

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well a typical Microsoft fix to the problem, I uninstalled Reporting Services from my SQL Server instance and reinstalled and re-configured everything and everything was fixed :)